# How to retrieve exact reason of the error from async HttpRequest?

Tags: dart

I am trying to figure out how to find out exact reason of (async) HttpRequest (from 'dart:html') failure, and, to be honest, I am a bit lost here.

The onError callback receives only HttpRequestProgressError object, which doesn't have anything useful, and the HttpRequest object itself has "status" set to "0" in case of failure, even console shows "Failed to load resource" with no details.

What I want is to know the exact reason - like "connection refused" or "host name not resolved".

Is this possible at all?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi.... there are few status codes for that from that you can find exact reason.

Comment: Where they are? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: I'm assuming you talk about the `dart:html` HttpRequest, not `dart:io`?

Comment: @MarioP: exactly. Sorry that I didn't mention this in the original question (corrected).

Comment: hey than also there is "int status" in Dart is it?

Comment: @mitB, sure there is. But as I've mentioned already - it is set to "0" regardless of the reason :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no property to report the error as detailed as you'd like. The reason is that JavaScript doesn't support this.

There are the properties `status` and `statusText` on the `HttpRequest` object (which you could get from your `HttpRequestProgressEvent` with `evt.target`, but those represent HTTP status codes. Every other error has the status code 0 - request failed. This could be anything, and the only place to look at is the browser's console, because this is an Exception thrown by the browser.

If your request was synchronous, you could surround the `send()` with a try-catch. If your request is async, this won't work.

Comment: Thank you... It seems that most of my problems have no solutions, otherwise I don't ask questions :)

Comment: And so should you put more info in the body of the response, you can access it via error.target.response

Answer (score -1):

[See here](http://c.dart-examples.com/api/dart-html/interface/eventtarget/httprequest/asynchronous)

```
#library('Request');

#import('dart:html');
#import("dart:json");

typedef void RequestHandler(String responseText);

typedef void ErrorHandler(String error);

class ResourceRequest {
  XMLHttpRequest request;
  RequestHandler _callbackOnSuccess;
  ErrorHandler _callbackOnFailure;

  ResourceRequest.openGet(String url, RequestHandler callbackOnSuccess, [ErrorHandler callbackOnFailure])
    :  request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      _callbackOnSuccess = callbackOnSuccess,
       _callbackOnFailure = callbackOnFailure {
    request.open("GET", url, async : true);
    request.on.loadEnd.add((XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent e) => onLoadEnd(e));
  }

  void send() {
    request.send();
  }

  void onLoadEnd(XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent event) {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      _callbackOnSuccess(request.responseText);
    } else if (_callbackOnFailure != null) {
      _callbackOnFailure(request.statusText);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but how is the link you have mentioned related to async processing in dart?

But regardless of this - I am talking about *callback* (onError in my case), i.e. when request is *completed* already (though failed), not about issuing an async request.

Comment: Okie.. :( sorry bro . I  have no idea about that.. I think you get error while processing.

Comment: Check it now...callbackOnFailure(request.statusText); this will give you status code on Call back failure..

Comment: It is empty. Probably, exactly because requests was not performed. And the code you have posted is from quite old version of dart, by the way.

Comment: Okei Friend.. :) i help you as much i know.. All the best :)